# Create multidimensional array recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, eval

The original array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'key1',
        'val' => 'val1'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key2:subkey1',
        'val' => 'val2'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key3:subkey2',
        'val' => 'val3'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey1',
        'val' => 'val4'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey2',
        'val' => 'val5'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey3',
        'val' => 'val6'
    )
);
```

And I want to generate a new array based on the original one that looks like this:

```
$result = array(
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => array(
        'subkey1' => 'val2'
    ),
    'key3' => array(
        'subkey2' => 'val3',
        'subkey3' => array(
            'subsubkey1' => 'val4',
            'subsubkey2' => 'val5',
            'subsubkey3' => 'val6'            
        )
    )
);
```

The algorithm should be able to handle a reference array of any depth.
What I have tried so far works, but I am not happy with using `eval` for various reasons:

```
function convert($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        $key = $data['key'];
        $pos = strpos($key, ':');
        if ($pos === false) {
            $out[$key] = $data['val'];
        } else {
            $split = explode(":", $key);
            eval("\$out['" . implode("']['", $split) . "'] = '" . $data['val'] . "';");
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this without resorting to `eval`, i.e. setting the `$out` directly? The `val` comes from user input, so it is obviously very unsafe to use `eval` in this case.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convert($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($array as $data) {
        $key = $data['key'];
        $value = $data['val'];
        $helper = &$out;
        foreach (explode(':', $key) as $i) {
            $helper = &$helper[$i];
        }
        $helper = $value;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Took me a while to figure out how to do it. References are perhaps the best way to achieve it.

The `$helper`-variable is a temporary reference to the `$out`-array we want to return after we're done. It splits each key by the colon as delimiter and iterates through each individual key. In every iteration we change the helper reference to the next key.

An example:

```
$out = array();

explode(':', $key) => array('key3', 'subkey3', 'subsubkey1');
$helper = &$out;

// foreach loop starts
$helper = $helper['key3']; // Iteration 1
$helper = $helper['key3']['subkey3']; // Iteration 2
$helper = $helper['key3']['subkey3']['subsubkey1']; // Iteration 3
```

I hope you understand how it works.

Comment: Great job. It suspected that it should be a reference couldn't get it working by myself. Yes I understand how it works. Very clean and simple solution. @silkfire you had been the first one with nearly the same solution but i accepted this one because of the descriptions and the clean function block. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this neat code:

```
$array = array(
               array(
                     'key' => 'key1',
                     'val' => 'val1'
                    ),
               array(
                     'key' => 'key2:subkey1',
                     'val' => 'val2'
                    ),
               array(
                     'key' => 'key3:subkey2',
                     'val' => 'val3'
                    ),
               array(
                     'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey1',
                     'val' => 'val4'
                    ),
               array(
                     'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey2',
                     'val' => 'val5'
                    ),
               array(
                     'key' => 'key3:subkey3:subsubkey3',
                     'val' => 'val6'
                    )
              );

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $element) {
    $temp = &$new_array;

    foreach(explode(':', $element['key']) as $key) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }

    $temp = $element['val'];
}

unset($temp);

var_dump($new_array);
```